# Unable to connect to vsftpd from Demandware

Tags: ftp

I have vsftpd running on my server on passive mode. I have set the pasv_min_port, and pasv_max_port as 14000 and 14050 respectively. I am able to connect to it from filezilla as well as all other systems.

But a customer of mine is using Demandware as their OMS and want to transfer some files from Demandware to the FTP server. However, when they try to connect, it timesout after a minute or so and gives a 221 error. The customer is not able to provide any detailed error messages. However, when they try to connect from Filezilla, it works. What could be the problem here?

Thanks.

Comment: 221 is not an error.

Comment: @KonradGajewski According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes), 221 means the server is closing the connection.

Comment: Any idea? Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

The FTP requests are being stopped by the Demandware firewall.

You need to file a ticket with Demandware to get this fixed.